Record setup for Mail Server
I'm stuck on a situation. For me to run a mail server on my NAS I first had to setup port forwarding for my router so that all email ports would direct to my NAS which is running the mail server.
The problem is, I need to setup a A record that points to my public IP address and by using only the name of the subdomain which I will be using for my mail server along with the public IP address and giving this A record a 1 hour TTL, nothing shows after the hour ?
Therefore am I doing this correctly when setting up an A record so that mail get routed to my NAS which is hosting the mail server. Also I want to let it be known that, I know that some don't suggest running mail server; this is only a storage mail server it won't be used as my regular mail server for daily mail.
I just want to know why this is not coming together as I've been struggling with this for over three weeks, any help is greatly appreciated.
